# if else statements inside enhanced for loop gives either corresponding answer or unknown word, now I get both?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, do-while

I'm having trouble constructing enhanced loop that gives me either corresponding answer OR unknown word. I have the arraylist corresponding part done, but my output is messed up.

My output should be:

```
Enter English word: hello
moi

Enter English word:asdasdsd
Unknown word

Enter English word:quit
Bye!
```

My output is now, keep getting these unknown words everywhere..

```
Enter English word: winter
talvi

Unknown word
Enter English word:hello
Uknown word
moi


Enter English word:quit
Unknown word
Unknown word
Bye!
```

Here is the part of the code I could use some help with.

```java
String eng;
do {
    System.out.print("Enter English word: ");
    eng = s.nextLine();

    for (WordPair wordObject : words) {
        if (wordObject.getEnglishWord().equals(eng)) {
            System.out.println(wordObject.getFinnishWord());
            System.out.println();
            
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unknown word");
        }
    }

} while (!eng.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"));
System.out.println("Bye!");
```

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger.

Comment: You are printing either the word or unknown word for **each** `WordPair`, so that means if you have two words (like you seem to have) in `words` then either it prints 2x "Unknown word" (if neither match), or 1x the Finnish word and 1x "Unknown word" (in either order). Maybe you should first **find** if there is a matching `WordPair`, and only then print the Finnish word or "Unknown word" if no match was found. Also, it would be helpful if you post a [mre] instead of an incomplete code fragment.

Comment: what is value of `words`

Answer (score 1):

You would need to break out of the `for` loop in your code once the word is found. Perhaps try this:

```
boolean found = false
for (WordPair wordObject : words) {
    if (wordObject.getEnglishWord().equalsIgnoreCase(eng)) {
        System.out.println(wordObject.getFinnishWord());
        System.out.println();
        found = true; 
        break; // found - no need to carry on.
    } 
}
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("Unknown word");
}
```